# Does complete bitachon necessarily eliminate or at least mitigate all anxiety one may experience?

Tags: sources-mekorot, faith-bitachon-emunah

Or put differently, does anxiety always indicate a lack of bitachon.

Some claim that bitachon does not (always) mitigate **or** eliminate anxiety (see the discussion here [1](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/anxiety-bitachon-and-morons-dah-mah-shetashiv-lmoron-2) and Rabbi Netanel Wiederblank here [2](https://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/lecture.cfm/887091/rabbi-netanel-wiederblank/question-answer-session-part-3-bitachon-and-benefiting-from-work-done-on-shabbat/), for instance). Others claim that bitachon does just that based upon the simple understanding of pesukim, such as אבטח ולא אפחד and the beginning of chovos halevavos shaar habitachon. Which view is correct? And more importantly, please provide sources that address this (as directly as possible).

Comment: There's a famous Chazon Ish that bitachon means "if Hashem wants it I will succeed, and if not not", so there's no room to completely fall apart into pieces. (RHS' example of falling to pieces would be trying quack medicine when all the mainstream doctors say the odds are slim.) I don't think that means one can't still feel anxious to some degree.

Comment: "Which view is correct?" is usually a bad question to ask here if you already know it's a machloket